# Do GADTs break equational reasoning in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have the following interpreter using ProgramT from the operational package

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Control.Monad ((<=<))
import Control.Monad.Operational

data Motor' a where
  --Define GADT

serialNewportT :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => ProgramT Motor' m a -> m a
serialNewportT = eval <=< viewT
  where
    eval :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => ProgramViewT Motor' m v -> m v
    eval (Return x) = return x
    eval (x :>>= k) = f x >>= serialNewportT  . k

f :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => Motor' a -> m a
f = undefined -- excluded for brevity
```

The code, as it stands, currently type checks just fine.  However, I want to be able to switch out how the interpreter handles different motors, so I want to make `f` a parameter, instead of having it hard coded in.  I've tried to make this switch with the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Control.Monad ((<=<))
import Control.Monad.Operational

data Motor' a where
  --Define GADT

serialNewportT :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => (Motor' a -> m a) -> ProgramT Motor' m a -> m a
serialNewportT f = eval <=< viewT
  where
    eval :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => ProgramViewT Motor' m v -> m v
    eval (Return x) = return x
    eval (x :>>= k) = f x >>= serialNewportT f . k
```

However, this code fails with an error message

```
Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘c’
   ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         :>>= :: forall (instr :: * -> *) (m :: * -> *) a b.
                 instr b -> (b -> ProgramT instr m a) -> ProgramViewT instr m a,
       in an equation for ‘eval’
   ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
         serialNewportT :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) =>
                           (Motor' c -> m c) -> ProgramT Motor' m a -> m a
 Expected type: Motor' c
   Actual type: Motor' b
```

Since I'm just replacing the global name with a local one of the same type, I would have thought that it should have worked without a hitch.  How can I get the types to unify with `f` as a parameter?

Comment: You have not correctly translated the type of `f`. In the original code, it could be instantiated with a type `Motor' a` for any `a`, but in the non-working code you state that it's type is precisely the same `a` as in `ProgramT Motor' m a`, whereas in the function body you call `f` on a `Motor' b` for some other (existentially quantifed) type `b`. You probably just need a higher rank type: `serialNewportT :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => (forall x . Motor' x -> m x) -> ProgramT Motor' m a -> m a`

Comment: @user2407038 seems like an answer to me

Comment: Ugh.  I did a bunch of research on scoped type variables trying to get everything to match, but didn't look at rank N types.  I guess it's time to finally learn them.  @user2407038, if you'd like to make this an answer, I'll give you the credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not correctly translated the type of f. In the original code, the type of `f` is `forall a . (..) => Motor' a -> m a`. It could be instantiated with a type `Motor' a` for *any* `a`, but in the non-working code you state that it's type is precisely the same `a` as in `ProgramT Motor' m a`, whereas in the function body you call `f` on a `Motor' b` for some other (existentially quantifed) type `b`.

You just need a higher rank type:

```
serialNewportT :: (Monad m, MonadIO m) => (forall x . Motor' x -> m x) -> ProgramT Motor' m a -> m a
```